# How to convert Dapper dynamic return type to a concrete class

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I have an async method that uses dapper to return a dynamic type, but in the calling method I want a concrete class. For example...

```
public async Task<dynamic> MyDapperMethod(string sql)
{
    var result = await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync(sql);
    return result;
}
```

Then in the calling method...

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int id)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();

    var qry = await MyDapperMethod($"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = {id}");
    cust = (Customer)qry;

    return cust;
}
```

I'm getting an invalid cast error. It cannot cast "DapperRow" to "Customer".
Is there some way I can fix this?

Some suggestions were to manually move each field in the DapperRow to its corresponding property in the concrete class. But is there a better way?

Comment: If you are committed to working with a `dynamic` (I'd recommend against it), then you'll need to write some code to convert the dynamic to an instance of the concrete type. One way would be to create a constructor that takes a `dynamic` as an argument and the sets the concrete type properties one-by-one. If you are going to be doing this a lot (with different types), you could create a generic worker that reflects over the concrete types and pulls things out of the dynamic. You need to realize once you get into dynamic-land, type-safety is off the table (you'll need an error handling strategy)

Comment: It's been about a week.  Were any of the answers you received useful?  Don't forget to upvote and/or accept useful answers

Answer (score 0):

Use the QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<>() Instead.

```
public async Task<Customer> MyDapperMethod(string sql)
{
    var result = await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Customer>(sql);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is *"Don't use `dynamic` for this"*.  However, I realize that sometimes you end up having to use some library code.  If you weren't going to use dynamic, you could change your `MyDapperMethod` to look something like what @sarmad proposed, something like:

```cs
public async Task<T> MyDapperMethod(string sql)
{
    var result = await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(sql);
    return result;
}
```

and you'd call it passing in your `Customer` type.

But, you'll notice that that method only abstracts your connection handling.  Otherwise, it looks pretty much like the raw Dapper call.

***Some Code Review**:

While we are at it, you are probably doing your connection handling the wrong way.  The `SqlConnection` type (like most `IDbConnection` implementations) expects consumers to create a new connection for each unit of work and then quickly dispose that new connection - it does pooling for you under the covers.*

So, if you are married to using `dynamic`, here are two possible solutions:

*1. Use a constructor that takes a `dynamic` parameter*

Create a constructor in your `Customer` class that looks something like:

```
public Customer (dynamic customerRecord){
    Name = customerRecord.Name;
    Address = customerRecord.Address;
    PhoneNumber = customerRecord.PhoneNumber;
    // etc.
}
```

With that, your `GetCustomer` ends up looking like:

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int id)
{
    var result = await MyDapperMethod($"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = {id}");
    return new Customer (result);
}
```

***More Code Review**

You don't need to initialize your `cust` variable when you declare it.  By doing what you are doing in your code, you run the default `Customer` constructor needlessly and you create garbage that needs to be cleaned up.  Also, **don't do string concatenation or interpolation with SQL queries** (look up "SQL Injection" and "Little Bobby Tables").  Your code should look like:*

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int id)
{
    var result = await MyDapperMethod($"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = @Id", new {Id = id});
    return new Customer (result);
}
```

I'm going to post this for now.  The reflection based solution is more involved - I need to get some work done.  I should be able to update this later.